# apt-get install re-attempts failed installs

Tags: unix, debian, apt-get

I've used apt-get to download some application some of which failed.  When I run apt-get now it looks like it keeps trying to download these previously failed installs.

Is there anyway to get rid of these?

> Errors were encountered while processing:
>
> motion
>
> sabnzbdplus
>
> sabnzbdplus-theme-smpl

Answer (score 0):

Is it failing to *download* those packages, or failing to *install* them? It sounds like apt started to install them but failed to complete the installation, typically due to a problem in one of the packages' installation scripts. This leaves the package in a half-installed state — technically, "installed" but not "configured" — and apt will make another attempt every time it runs.

You can explicitly tell apt to uninstall the packages, which will remove the incomplete installation and make apt stop trying to fully install them.

Alternatively, you can try to resolve the problem that's preventing the installation from completing. Look at the log messages produced by apt, above the "errors were encountered" line, for clues as to what's wrong.